# Insert data in database using checkbox different row

Tags: php, mysql

Scenario: I am developing a sales and inventory system and I am on the Purchase Order stage now. What I am trying to do is to insert a data of checkbox to the database for item_po table.

Scenario: I already generate all the items that have below minimum stock (need to replenish). I add a checkbox on the left side of the data generated (see picture for reference). I want to insert that data to my item_po table and prepare it for generation of reports base on the items checked for purchase order. Is that possible?

This is my current code for insert but it's not working.

```
<?php
require_once('../../inc/config/constants.php');
require_once('../../inc/config/db.php');

$itemDetailsSearchSql = 'SELECT * FROM item WHERE stock < itemMinStock';
$itemDetailsSearchStatement = $conn->prepare($itemDetailsSearchSql);
$itemDetailsSearchStatement->execute();



$output = '<table id="itemMinStockReportsTable" class="table table-sm table-bordered table-hover" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 10px !important;"><input type="checkbox" name="check" class="cbxMain" onchange="checkMain(this)"/></th>
                    <th>Lookup Code</th>
                    <th>Item Name</th>
                
                    <th>Current Stock</th>
                    <th>Unit Cost</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Minimum Stock</th>
                    <th>Vendor</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>';

// Create table rows from the selected data
while($row = $itemDetailsSearchStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$itemNumber = $row['itemNumber'];
$itemName = $row['itemName'];
$stock = $row['stock'];
$unitPrice = $row['unitPrice'];
$status = $row['status'];
$description = $row['description'];
$itemMinStock = $row['itemMinStock'];
$itemVendor = $row['itemVendor'];

    $output .= '<tr>' .
                    
                    '<td>' . ' <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="check"  '. '</td> '. 
                    '<td>' . $itemNumber . '</td>' .
                    //'<td>' . $row['itemName'] . '</td>' .
                    '<td><a href="#" class="itemDetailsHover" data-toggle="popover" id="' . $row['productID'] . '">' . $itemName . '</a></td>' .
    
                    '<td>' . $stock. '</td>' .
                    '<td>' . $unitPrice. '</td>' .
                    '<td>' . $status . '</td>' .
                    '<td>' . $description . '</td>' .
                    '<td>' . $itemMinStock . '</td>' .
                    '<td>' . $itemVendor . '</td>' .
                    '<td>' .'<button type="button" id="deleteItem" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button> '. '</td>' .
                '</tr>';
}

$itemDetailsSearchStatement->closeCursor();

$output .= '</tbody>
                <tfoot>
            
                <br>
                <th> <br>   <button type="button" id="addItem" name="btn_po" class="btn btn-success">Proceed to PO</button> </th>
            
                 </tfoot>
            </table>';
echo $output;


if(isset($_POST['btn_po']))
{
   $checkbox = $_POST['check'];         
   for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++)
   {
        $check_id = $checkbox[$i];


        $stockSql = 'SELECT stock FROM item WHERE itemNumber=:itemNumber';
            $stockStatement = $conn->prepare($stockSql);
            $stockStatement->execute(['itemNumber' => $itemNumber]);
            if($stockStatement->rowCount() > 0){
                //$row = $stockStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                //$quantity = $quantity + $row['stock'];
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>Item already exists in DB. Please click the <strong>Update</strong> button to update the details. Or use a different Item Number.</div>';
                exit();
            } else {
                // Item does not exist, therefore, you can add it to DB as a new item
                // Start the insert process
                $insertItemSql = 'INSERT INTO item_po(itemNumber,itemName,stock,unitPrice,status,description,itemMinStock,itemMaxStock,itemVendor) VALUES (:itemNumber, :itemName,:stock, :unitPrice, :status, :description, :itemMinStock, :itemVendor)';

                $insertItemStatement = $conn->prepare($insertItemSql);
                $insertItemStatement->execute(['itemNumber' => $itemNumber, 'itemName' => $itemName, 'stock' => $stock, 'unitPrice' => $unitPrice, 'status' => $status, 'description' => $description, 'itemMinStock' => $itemMinStock, 'itemVendor' => $itemVendor   ]);

                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>Item failed to insert in database.</div>';
                exit();
        }
    }
}

?>
```

[image]

Comment: You also need to wrap the data inside <td> an `<input>` tag, give **field array name** like `name='data1[]'` then get this value with `$_POST` or `$_GET` after form submission.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple row insert to table if check box is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30182150/multiple-row-insert-to-table-if-check-box-is-selected). Beware that your code is open to [SQL Injections](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). You should use parameterized prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your `checkbox` is should be inside a `<form>` tag.

Also, you need to **wrap** all data you need inside  with `<input>` tag and give each column **field array name** like `name=data1[]` so you can retrieve back the data after you submit the form. ( You can use **$_GET[ ]** or **$_POST[ ]** method ).

**Updated sample#1**: Completed form

Just a sample. You can add your **MySQL INSERT** inside `foreach()`, where it will traverse through each row having checkbox `checked`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Multiple Checkbox Form: Insert data only when Checkbox is checked</title>
<style type="text/css">
    table{
        width:250px;
    }
    table td {
        padding:5px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    <table id="table">
        <tr>
            <?php $id = 1; ?>
            <td> <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" <?= in_array('1',$_POST['check'])? 'checked' : ''; ?> ></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="name[<?php echo $id; ?>]" placeholder="name" value="Name1"/>Name1</td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="age[<?php echo $id; ?>]" placeholder="age" value="Age1">Age1</td>
            <td><button class="delBtn">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <?php $id = 2; ?>
            <td> <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" <?= in_array('2',$_POST['check'])? 'checked' : ''; ?>></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="name[<?php echo $id; ?>]" placeholder="name" value="Name2"/>Name2</td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="age[<?php echo $id; ?>]" placeholder="age" value="Age2">Age2</td>
            <td><button class="delBtn">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <?php $id = 3; ?>
            <td> <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" <?= in_array('3',$_POST['check'])? 'checked' : ''; ?>></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="name[<?php echo $id; ?>]" placeholder="name" value="Name3"/>Name3</td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="age[<?php echo $id; ?>]" placeholder="age" value="Age3">Age3</td>
            <td><button class="delBtn">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Proceed to PO">
</form>

<div id="result">
    <p>Data sent to PO DB:</p>
    <ol>
        <?php
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
                $name=$_POST['name']; //array received
                $age=$_POST['age']; //array received
                $checks=$_POST['check']; //array received (checked only)
                $i = 0;
                /* Foreach checked checkbox: Echo each data row */
                /* Add your Insert Query Here */
                foreach($checks as $key=>$check) //loop through all checks that are sent
                {
                    echo "<li>[Name ".$check."] = ".$name[$check].", [Age ".$check."] = ".$age[$check]."</li>";
                }
            }
        ?>
    </ol>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello sir thank you for answering my question . I just need to insert all the data that checked . Base on your answer I need to fill out my <TD> with the array name? I tried this but no luck sir it doesnt inserting the data on the database .

Comment: Yes I know, need to insert data that's checked. You need to wrap your data with `<input>` tag. For example: Instead of `<td>Data</td>` , it should be `<td><input type='text' name='data1[]' value='Data'/>Data</td>`. You can also use `type='hidden'`

Comment: Im gonna try this out. Please hang on sir I really need this to finish T.T

Comment: Okay, keep me updated with your progress. In the mean time, I've updated my answer, added a complete form, you can try to run it. Basically set a specific/unique key to name attribute for each row. You can use `$id` or any key to uniquely identify each row. Then use this `key` to get the data of each row with `checked` checkbox.

Comment: Hi sir sorry late reply. I cant apply the code because Im using ajax how can I apply this to ajax. that is why I dnt have a form because Im using ajax.

Comment: Hello phantom, actually it does not matter if you're using Ajax or not. If you're using ajax, simply send the data in `data` parameter, like `data: data_to_send`.

Comment: Hi Im getting this error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$productID' (T_VARIABLE) in F:\xampp\htdocs\rct\model\item\itemReportsSearchMinStockTableCreator.php on line 42" I think I have a contact problem here is my code ' '<td>' . ' <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="<?php echo $productID; ?>" <?= in_array('$productID',$_POST['check'])? 'checked' : ''; ?>   '. '</td> '.'

Comment: You shouldn't put a `' '` quote for `$productID` inside **in_array()** function since it is  a php variable.

Comment: Now this is my error sir "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'check' (T_STRING) in F:\xampp\htdocs\rct\model\item\itemReportsSearchMinStockTableCreator.php on line 42
"

Comment: You also miss a closing tag `>` for your `<input>`, and also make sure the `' '` quotes you're using matches.

Comment: Hi sir I check if the data is retrieving so yes the product id retrieving successfully I just change the input type to text for me to check ang I try to remove the array and there is no error this is my current code now "  '<td>' . ' <input type="text" name="check[]" value="' . $row['productID'] . '"  >   '. '</td> '." . I need to figure out how to fix the code on in_array

Comment: Try to use this `<?= in_array($productID,$_POST["check"])? "checked" : ""; ?>`

Comment: Any progress yet? Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235573/discussion-between-ncxnav-and-phantom).

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493531/send-multiple-checkbox-data-to-php-via-jquery-ajax) to send multiple checkbox data to php via jquery ajax. You still need to wrap all `<td>` values with `<input>` and give each **array field name**, same method, the difference is using Ajax to send the `$_POST[]` data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235573/discussion-between-ncxnav-and-phantom).